# Parameter in REST method is not properly handled in Retrofit

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit

I'm working on Android app which connects to REST and invokes a method. This is Embarcadero REST DataSnap.
Using parameters like "@Query" is good when you invoke method like that:

> www.app.net/api/searchtypes/862189/filters?Type=6&SearchText=School

However, here methods are invoked differently:

> /datasnap/rest/some_class/some_method/some_parameter

Below is simple class to handle parameter which goes in request body:

```
public class Dane {
    private int NAGL;

    public Dane(int NAGL) {
        this.NAGL = NAGL;
    }
}
```

When I try to use Retrofit annotation @Query, for example:

```
 @POST("datasnap/rest/TstBaseMethods/%22SelectSQL%22/{aSelectSQL}")   
Call<Logowanie> selectSQL(@Header("Authorization") String credentials,@Body Dane json,@Query("aSelectSQL") String aSelectSQL);

String dane = Credentials.basic("admin","admin");  
Dane json = new Dane(11101); 


Call<Logowanie> sql = gerritAPI.selectSQL(dane,json,"select n.datadok from nagl n where n.id_nagl =:NAGL");
```

and I launch the app, I see in logs

> TstBaseMethods.SelectSQL: {aSelectSQL} << {"NAGL":11101}

The content of aSelectSQL is not sent to the server. I've already noticed that if I hardcode the content into URL and I invoke this as below, it works:

```
@POST("datasnap/rest/TstBaseMethods/%22SelectSQL%22/select%20n.datadok%20from%20nagl%20n%20where%20n.id_nagl%3D%3Anagl")
 Call<Logowanie> selectSQL(@Header("Authorization") String credentials,@Body Dane json);
```

Is there any way to pass properly content of the parameter to the server? It won't be good to hardcode all parameters in URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in retrofit, the @Query annotation is used for query parameter. 
It will add your parameter as a query parameter, for example:

```
@GET("/api/somePath")
Call<JSONObject> getSomething(@Query("foo") String foo);
...
service.getSomething("bar")
```

Will actually result in the url:

```
https://yoursite.com/api/somePath?foo=bar
```

Here, in your case, you are using {} inside the url, which indicates retrofit that you are adding a path parameter. So your post should be like this

```
@POST("datasnap/rest/TstBaseMethods/%22SelectSQL%22/{aSelectSQL}") 
Call<Logowanie> selectSQL(@Header("Authorization") String credentials,@Body Dane json,@Path("aSelectSQL") String aSelectSQL);
```

Comment: It looks like it's ok. I will check it tomorrow more precisely, because it's already after midnight for me.
Thanks, I need to understand those annotations more.